# Finding the volume of a rectangular prism using only surface area

Tags: geometry

Three surfaces of a rectangular prism are 25 cm squared, 18 cm squared, and 8 cm squared. What is its volume?

Can someone please explain how to solve the problem without using guess and check? The book where I found this problem said the answer is 60 cm squared but I don't know how to get to that answer.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you fail? What did your attempt consist of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The volume of a rectangular prism is $abc$, where $a,b,c$ are the lengths in the three dimensions. You have $ab = 25$, $ac=18$, $bc=8$. What happens if you multiply these equations together?

Comment: Omg thanks Théophile! I got it now :)